# how do i get the program to close depending on a decision?

Tags: python

so I am new to python and wanted the most simplest easiest way to close down a program completely here is my code feel free to edit it :

```
    welcome_message = input("Welcome to the  yes or now game press enter to begin")
User_Question = True
while User_Question:
Question_yn = input("Would You Like To Play?")
if Question_yn == "Y" or Question_yn == "y":
    User_Question = False 
elif Question_yn == "N" or Question_yn =="n":
    User_Question = True
elif Question_yn != "N" or "n":
    print("Error Invalid Syntax!")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but `elif Question_yn != "N" or "n"` is not going to have the behavior you want it to have.

Comment: You really need to have a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: @Kevin although it sort of will just by dumb luck of his arguments ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley, heh, I guess you're right :-D

Comment: Insisting that people answer your question isn't nearly as effective a learning tool as doing some basic research and answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loop to continue running, User_Question needs to be True. You are setting it false if the user wants to continue, which is the opposite.

```
welcome_message = raw_input("Welcome to the  yes or now game press enter to begin")
User_Question = True
while User_Question:
    Question_yn = input("Would You Like To Play?")
    if Question_yn == "Y" or Question_yn == "y":
        User_Question = True 
    elif Question_yn == "N" or Question_yn =="n":
        User_Question = False
    else:
        continue
```

Your last elif statement is stating that if the input is not N or n then break out of the loop. This is not catching all invalid input, though technically by the way you structured it it wouldn't necessarily fail. What will happen is that none of the if statements would be True and so the loop would just continue.

EDIT: Seeing that you want to break on invalid input (though it would be better if you gave the user more tries to enter the correct input) change `else: continue` to `else: break`.

Comment: `else: continue` is superfluous, by the way.

Comment: no, because that would repeat the question and when "y" is typed it repeats the question

Comment: that doesn't exactly bother me, my main concern is closing the program if something else than "n" is typed

Comment: it won't close the program. if something other than n is put (assuming not y or Y obviously) the condition for the while doesn't change. the loop will continue. so yes, in a way it is superfluous, but force of habit for me.

Comment: What was your question then? I thought you said simplest way to close out of your loop. If you want to break out of the loop when the user types N or n then the above code takes care of that. if you want to break on invalid input then instead of `else: continue` put `else: break`.